# passing query data to send in mail laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a query to return all the the data in visits table

```
$visits = Visit::get();
```

i want to pass  the returned data in  $data so that i can send it on mail  and display the data in the email body

```
$data = array();


        Mail::send('mails.mail', $data, function ($message) use ($host_email, $to_name) {
            $message->from('', '');
            $message->to($host_email);
            $message->subject('Visitor arrived');

        });
```

how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel structure, You can create a mail class with this command:

```
php artisan make:mail OrderShipped
```

it will generate a class in App\Mail path sample named OrderShipped in build method you can call a blade view for this mail and send data to it like:

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                    ->with([
                        'orderName' => $this->order->name,
                        'orderPrice' => $this->order->price,
                    ]);
    }
```

and finally use this to send email to user:

```
Mail::to($request->user())->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

look here for full documentation:
[laravel mail](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail)